# Defining a fallback view in traversal

Tags: python, pyramid, traversal

Consider the following Pyramid application:

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator

class Foo(dict):
    pass

def make_root(request):
    return {'foo': Foo()}

def foo(request):
    return request.subpath

def bar(request):
    return {"whoami": "bar", "subpath": request.subpath}

def start(global_config, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.set_root_factory(make_root)
    config.add_view(foo, context=Foo, renderer="json")
    config.add_view(bar, name="bar", context=Foo, renderer="json")
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

This application uses Traversal and responds to `/foo` and `/foo/bar` just fine.  I was wondering if, when traversing `/foo/booarns`, there was some place to hook at before Traversal decides to return a 404.  Something like a default, or *fallback* view:

```
config.add_view(any_other, name="*default*", context=Foo, ...)
```

Then, this view would be invoked whenever the second component of the path has not been bound to any other view, in the same context, having the path components still available as `request.view_name` and `request.subpath`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `containment` predicate will still work here.

```
@notfound_view_config(containment=Foo)
def notfound(request):
    return HTTPNotFound('no views for Foo detected for view %s' % request.view_name)
```

Comment: Indeed.  It would have never occured to me, as it's very well hidden in the API reference.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/glossary.html#term-default-view), you just need to specify an empty string for the name:

```
config.add_view(any_other, name="", context=Foo, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

When Pyramid is unable to map a URL to view code, it triggers a "not found view".  The default "not found view" can be overridden through application configuration using the following:

```
from pyramid.view import notfound_view_config

@notfound_view_config()
def notfound(request):
    return Response('Not Found, dude', status='404 Not Found')

def main(globals, **settings):
   config = Configurator()
   config.scan()
```

Comment: But then I'd have to dispatch myself if I want to do this separately for different contexts, right?

Comment: The `notfound_view_config()` decorator is triggered anytime an internal NotFound response is received.